# Problemas con conexión PHP Error HY000/1045

Tags: php, mysql, conexión

He estado practicando hacer una api con un tutorial de youtube pero no encuentro la solución a este problema. He revisado los datos, que el usuario y pass esté todo correcto pero no encuentro como solucionarlo.

El error que me tira es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado viendo otras soluciones sobre verificar el archivo config.inc.php y sql.mi, sobre los usuarios y contraseñas, todo figura en **root** sin contraseña y está en TRUE la opción de permitir usuario sin contraseña. He probado reescribir el codigo a ver si hay algún problema pero sigo igual sin poder resolver el problema.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
    private $server;
    private $user; 
    private $password; 
    private $database;
    private $port ;
    private $conexion;


    function __construct(){
        $listadatos = $this->datosConexion();
        foreach ($listadatos as $key => $value) {
            $this-> server =$value ['server'];
            $this-> user =$value ['user'];
            $this-> password =$value ['password'];
            $this-> database =$value ['database'];
            $this-> port =$value ['port'];
        }
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->server,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database,$this->port);
        if($this->conexion->connect_errno){
            echo"algo va mal con la conexion";
            die();
        }
    }

    private function datosConexion(){
        $direccion = dirname(__FILE__);
        $jsondata = file_get_contents($direccion. "/" . "config");
        return json_decode($jsondata, true);

    }


}




?>
```

mi config

```
"conexion":{
    "server":"localhost",
    "user":"root",
    "password":"",
    "database":"API",
    "port":"3306"
}
```

el index

```
<?php
    require_once "clases/conexion/conexion.php";
    $conexion = new conexion;
?>
```

**UPDATE**

ya solucioné el error, me faltaban unas {} al inicio del archivo config :')
Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: El método `$this->datosConexion();` está devolviendo `null` en vez del valor esperado. Probablemente no encuentra el archivo de configuración o el contenido no está en formato JSON válido. Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/516545/edit) para agregar lo que tienes en ese archivo. No olvides cambiar datos sensibles, como ruta de servidor, usuario o contraseña.

Comment: Si era un error tipográfico y ya lo tienes solucionado puedes eliminar la pregunta tranquilamente. Gracias.